# Is there a way to set ro.kernel.qemu to 0 in a emulator?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I replaced a modified build.prop which contains `ro.kernel.qemu=0` to the system.img with yaffey, but it did not work. When the emulator restarted, `ro.kernel.qemu=1` still exists in the output of `adb shell getprop` .

EDIT:

I also tried:

1. add `ro.kernel.qemu=0` in default.prop in ramdisk.img
2. add `setprop ro.kernel.qemu 0` in init.goldfish.rc in ramdisk.img

But all these did not work. When I start the emulator with modified ramdisk.img, `ro.kernel.qemu` is still 1 in the output of `adb shell getprop`.

I am now trying to rebuild the kernel to set it to 0, but I did not find where `ro.kernel.qemu` is set in the kernel source code.

Appreciated for any advices.

Comment: Is it OK if you can change the ro.kernel.qemu from /data/local.prop? Or you only wants it via default.prop or  init.goldfish.rc ?

Comment: @AADTechnical Changing the value in `/data/local.prop`, 'default.prop` or `init.goldfish.rc` did not work, I still got `ro.kernel.qemu=1` when executing `adb shell getprop` after that.

Comment: you could try https://github.com/jduck/rootadb , it allows setting ro property values, specifically you can just use the native part of the app setpropex to set the ro values from su shell, but needs to be set on each reboot

Comment: @nandeesh In an emulator, root privilege is already got.

Comment: yeah, so setpropex might work

Comment: @nandeesh Unfortunately, `setpropex` can not set `ro.kernel.qemu` either.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify ramdisk.img which contains /init and the initial property files.
system.img is mounted later, so any changes there will not affect the boot.

Also, init might need to be modified, because it might set the ro.kernel.xxxxx variables from the kernel command-line *before* parsing the boot property config file.

Comment: I did unzip the ramdisk.img and did not find where `ro.kernel.qemu` is set.

Comment: I mean `ro.kernel.qemu` is neither set in `init.rc` nor in `default.prop`.

Comment: ro.kernel.xxx variables are set by init from the kernel's parameters (i.e. /proc/cmdline, iirc). In this specific case, the emulator sets a parameter "qemu=1" on startup, and that's why ro.kernel.qemu is defined to 1 by init on startup.

I.e. you will have to either modify the emulator, or the init program on your ramdisk.img to achieve what you want. Not setting ro.kernel.qemu might modify the way system libraries behave under emulation and may render your system un-bootable or un-usable.

Have fun :-)

Comment: I am trying to modify the emulator or init program but don't know how. Could you please give some more detail information?